How to bake the textures of a decal mesh onto the textures of the base mesh?
I've got a base mesh here with a color, emissive, normal, and roughness map, and surrounding this mesh (see selected) is another mesh that includes a similar texture set (plus an opacity mask) for the windows and escape pods. In the name of simplicity, I'd like to project the appropriate details of the texture set onto the base texture. If anyone could give me an idea of how to accomplish this, I'd be very grateful

